# Python requests.get vs Session.get

Tags: json, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using python request to fetch data from an API

The API I am using gives this in their documentation:

```
response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
```

But the tutorial I read uses:

```
tes = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, params={'term': 'cat', 'limit': 1})
```

What is the difference and what should I use?

Answer (score 4):

Use `requests.get()` if you only want to fetch a **single Item**, don't need to login first and don't need cookies to be persistent.

The documentation at [requests.readthedocs.io](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#request-and-response-objects) says:

> [`requests.get()` does not have] some of the advantages of having a Requests Session object. In particular, Session-level state such as cookies will not get applied to your request.

You can still send and receive cookies with `requests.get()` but you would need to manage them yourself.

---

Use `Session.get()` if you have a more complex task that requires persistent cookies. Or you want to speed up multiple requests to the same host.

The documentation at [requests.readthedocs.io](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) says

> The Session object allows you to **persist** certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

Comment: thanks that made it clear!